# HTC Hero - How to delete all calendar entries?

Tags: calendar, htc-hero

Currently i am developing a calendar based application from which i am inserting events into the native calendar of HTC HERO (Firmware version: Android 2.1 update 1).

At this point, calendar is full of events so i have tried lot to delete events, but by one by one event it takes long time to delete all events. I have also try to "Remove calendars" and then "Add calendars" shown as below:

[image]

This options are showing while clicking on "Press **menu button -> More -> Calendars**" while watching a calendar view.

One more try i have done, that is, i have also done "Clear data" in "Calendar storage" from "**Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Calendar storage -> clear data**". I think this is not deleting events actually as it is showing events inside the calendar same as earlier.

So, **how do i delete all the entries from the Calendar?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Calendar App syncs with Google Calendar - why don't you create a "Test" calendar, add events to that calendar and then delete the calendar from a web browser on your computer?

[image]

I just did this myself and it worked fine.

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani did this answer your question?